# Using translateX on overflowing div is causing white space flickering in FireFox

Tags: css, firefox

I'm making a site with a background gradient that slowly animates.  To do it, I'm making a very large gradient (~10,000px wide) with a pattern that repeats twice and using transforms inside a keyframe animation to translate it by 50% before repeating.  It works great in chrome but is super buggy in firefox.  Firefox can handle the translation (I checked by adjusting it manually) but chokes when I put it inside of the animation.

Here is a visual of how it looks in chrome vs firefox

**Chrome**
http://i.imgur.com/iI6he84.gifv

**Firefox**
http://i.imgur.com/nf8T478.gifv

Relevant HTML & SCSS (I have autoprefixer running...)

```css
@keyframes shift-bg {
  0% { transform: translateX(0%); }
  100% { transform: translateX(-50%); }
}

main {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.section {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.home-background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 10000px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right top,color-stop(0,#A4C4D1),color-stop(16%,#FEC746),color-stop(33%,#A3D282),color-stop(50%,#A4C4D1),color-stop(66%,#FEC746),color-stop(83%,#A3D282),color-stop(100%,#A4C4D1));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(10deg,#A4C4D1 0,#FEC746 16%,#A3D282 33%,#A4C4D1 50%,#FEC746 66%,#A3D282 83%,#A4C4D1 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(10deg,#A4C4D1 0,#FEC746 16%,#A3D282 33%,#A4C4D1 50%,#FEC746 66%,#A3D282 83%,#A4C4D1 100%);
background: linear-gradient(80deg,#A4C4D1 0,#FEC746 16%,#A3D282 33%,#A4C4D1 50%,#FEC746 66%,#A3D282 83%,#A4C4D1 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#A4C4D1', endColorstr='#A3D282', GradientType=1 )
  will-change: transform;
  animation-name: shift-bg;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<main>      
  <section id="home">
    <div class="home-background"></div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Anyone dealt with this before?  Is there a fix for firefox?  Otherwise I'll try a different solution all together..

Comment: Transitions and 3d css are still buggy in firefox from my experience, and of course it greatly depends on what device you're running firefox on.

Comment: same problem,has anyone solved it?